# I can't figure out the issue with this linked list code written with c

Tags: c, linked-list

So i have declared this open hashing (or separate chaining) array of 9 singly linked list nodes initially initialized to NULL in the main function:

```
//Initialize HashMap array
struct node *HashMap[9];
int HM_indx = 0;
for(HM_indx=0;HM_indx<9;HM_indx++)
    HashMap[HM_indx] = NULL;
```

This is how the struct of node is defined outside of the main function and not inside any function:

```
struct node
{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Then a function call to: Insert_Title_To_HashMap_Using_HashMapKey from the main function passes the address of HashMap in this manner:

```
for(x=0;x<sz;x++){
    HMKey = Compute_HashMapKey_for_each_title(SearchTitle[x]);
    //printf("%s\n", HMKey);
    Insert_Title_To_HashMap_Using_HashMapKey(SearchTitle[x], HMKey, HashMap);
}
```

Of course SearchTitle[x] and HMkey are also passed along. HMKey holds integer values from the range 0-9 returned from the hash function: Compute_HashMapKey_for_each_title(SearchTitle[x]) and SearchTitle[x] holds each of these values depending on the pass:

```
char *SearchTitle[6] = {"duel","dule","speed","spede","deul","cars"};
```

Now Insert_Title_To_HashMap_Using_HashMapKey is defined thus:

```
void Insert_Title_To_HashMap_Using_HashMapKey(char title[], char *HashMapKey, char *HM){
    int LDHMKeyACodeSum;
    size_t title_len = strlen(title);
    LDHMKeyACodeSum = Get_Last_Digit_Of_Sum_Of_Ascii_Equivalent_For_Each_HashMapKey_Character(HashMapKey);
    //Initialize newnode
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //Assign title to newnode value
    newnode->data = (char*)malloc(title_len + 1);
    strncpy(newnode->data, title, title_len);
    //Assign Null value to link part of newnode
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(HM[LDHMKeyACodeSum] == NULL){//if the headnode of the particular node where we are to insert title is NULL
        HM[LDHMKeyACodeSum] = newnode; //make newnode HeadNode
    }else{
        //Initialize tempnode for traversing the list
        //struct node *tempnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        struct node *tempnode = HM[LDHMKeyACodeSum]; //point tempnode to HeadNode
        while(tempnode->next != NULL){
            tempnode = tempnode->next; //move to next tempnode link part
        }//End While
        tempnode->next = newnode; //point tempnode link part to newnode
    }//end if
}
```

Everything else in the full code works as expected but what i can't figure out is why the code gets to this line: while(tempnode->next != NULL){ on the second pass and dies out and even exits the debugger mode.

All i can see in the log file is this message: [Inferior 1 (process 11288) exited with code 030000000005]
Debugger finished with status 0

I have google the error message and can't find anything useful.

Please i will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `char *HM` is a `char pointer` whereas the passed parameter `HashMap` is a `struct node*`

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday hahaha, this is what happens when you  start naming your functions & variables too logically XD

Comment: @anirudh Thank you very much for spotting that HM is a pointer of char instead of struct node. That punished me for some hours and i don't even know why i didn't spot it. Thanks so much. I wish you gave it as an answer, i should vote for it.

Comment: I took it literally...hahaha @eedideyahoocom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *HM` is a char pointer whereas the passed parameter HashMap is a `struct node*`